# Get Layout Shape Corresponding to Slide Shape

Tags: vba, powerpoint

In PowerPoint 2007 and using VBA, how can I get the placeholder shape on a Slide Master layout that is the "master" for a placeholder shape on the slide?

I am currently using a loop to compare the position and size of the slide placeholder with the position and shape of each placeholder shape in the slide's layout, but this isn't fool-proof.  For example, if the placeholder shape is moved on the slide, its position may no longer match the position of any placeholder shapes in the slide's layout.  I could reapply the slide's layout to snap placeholders back into position, but that's not what I want to do.

Something in the object model like `Shape.Master` would be ideal but, of course, that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

Seeing as there is still no answer to this here or elsewhere I might as well post my code.

> For example, if the placeholder shape is moved on the slide,

Here's what I came up with to handle that:

- store the locations of all shapes
- reset the slide layout
- match slide shapes and master slide shapes
- restore the locations of all shapes.

This is the function that does that and returns a mastershapename - shapename mapping.

```c#
private Dictionary<string, string> GetShapeMasters(Powerpoint.Slide s)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> shapeMasters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    List<ShapeLocation> shapeLocations = new List<ShapeLocation>();

    //store locations
    foreach (Powerpoint.Shape sh in s.Shapes)
    {
        shapeLocations.Add(new ShapeLocation()
        {
            Name = sh.Name,
            Location = new System.Drawing.RectangleF(sh.Left, sh.Top, sh.Width, sh.Height)
        });
    }

    //have powerpoint reset the slide
    //ISSUE: this changes the names of placeholders without content.
    s.CustomLayout = s.CustomLayout;

    //compare slide and master
    foreach (Powerpoint.Shape sh in s.Shapes)
    {
        foreach (Powerpoint.Shape msh in s.CustomLayout.Shapes)
        {
            if (IsShapeMaster(sh, msh))
            {
                shapeMasters[msh.Name] = sh.Name;
            }
        }
    }

    //restore locations
    //TODO: might be replaced by undo
    foreach (var shm in shapeLocations)
    {
        Powerpoint.Shape sh = null;
        try
        {
            sh = s.Shapes[shm.Name];
        }
        catch 
        {
            //Fails for renamed placeholder shapes.
            //Have yet to find a decent way to check if a shape name exists.
        }

        //placeholders do not need to be restored anyway.
        if (sh != null)
        {
            sh.Left = shm.Location.Left;
            sh.Top = shm.Location.Top;
            sh.Width = shm.Location.Width;
            sh.Height = shm.Location.Height;
        }
    }

    return shapeMasters;
}
```

With this you can do

```c#
Dictionary<string, string> shapeMasters = GetShapeMasters(theSlide);
if(shapeMasters.ContainsKey("KnownPlaceholderName"))
    Powerpoint.Shape KnownShape = theSlide[shapeMasters["KnownPlaceholderName"]];
```

And here is the comparison function that takes two shapes and checks if they are "equal". Could be extended to make it more precise.

```c#
private bool IsShapeMaster(Powerpoint.Shape sh, Powerpoint.Shape msh)
{
    return
        sh.Left == msh.Left
        && sh.Top == msh.Top
        && sh.Width == msh.Width
        && sh.Height == msh.Height
        && sh.Type == msh.Type
        && sh.PlaceholderFormat.Type == msh.PlaceholderFormat.Type;
}
```

Little class that stores original shape location

```c#
class ShapeLocation
{
    public string Name;
    public System.Drawing.RectangleF Location;
}
```

This is code from a C# VSTO Add-in but I suppose it is not that different from VB or other PPT automation types.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go Ryan, I believe this is what you're asking for.

```
Sub GetLayoutShapeDetails()
Dim myPPT As Presentation
Set myPPT = ActivePresentation
Dim mySlide As Slide
Set mySlide = myPPT.Slides(6)
Dim slideShape As Shape
Dim slideLayoutShape As Shape
Set slideShape = mySlide.Shapes(1)
If slideShape.Type = msoPlaceholder Then
    Dim placeHolderType As Integer
    placeHolderType = slideShape.PlaceholderFormat.Type
    Set slideLayoutShape = mySlide.CustomLayout.Shapes.Placeholders(placeHolderType)
    Dim modifiedPlaceHolder As String
    modifiedPlaceHolder = "Shape Name: " & slideShape.Name & _
        ", Left: " & slideShape.Left & _
        ", Width: " & slideShape.Width
    Dim originalPlaceHolder As String
    originalPlaceHolder = "Shape Name: " & slideLayoutShape.Name & _
        ", Left: " & slideLayoutShape.Left & _
        ", Width: " & slideLayoutShape.Width
    Debug.Print modifiedPlaceHolder
    Debug.Print originalPlaceHolder
End If
End Sub
```

---

**EDIT:** JAN 16, 2010
Based off of further research, there doesn't not appear to be a way in VBA to find a shape's corresponding exact match in its slide's layout.

Comment: Thanks, Otaku, but that doesn't do it.  PlaceholderFormat.Type is not an Index, as you have used it here.  Furthermore, it seems your solution implies that there is no more than one placeholder of each type in the layout.

Comment: I'm not sure by what you mean "PlaceholderFormat.Type is not an index" - it's an enum. For example, 1 is "ppPlaceholderTitle" and 2 is "ppPlaceholderBody". That is how you find out what the parent of the placeholder shape is - unless you're not looking for that and are needing something else. Also, there can be plenty of placeholders on the slide - I didn't provide a "solution" per se, just some sample code to allow you to further refine it as you need, check for other placeholders, etc.

Comment: So, suppose there are 4 placeholders on a slide with type ppPlaceholderChart and populated with charts.  How can I reference the placeholder in the slide's layout that corresponds to the second chart on the slide using this method?

mySlide.CustomLayout.Shapes.Placeholders(ppPlaceholderChart) returns a ShapeRange of 4 placeholders, but how can I tell which of them corresponds to the second chart?

Comment: When you say "second chart", what do you mean? The one in the top right corner? The one in the bottom left corner? The second one selected?

Comment: Second, third, fourth; it doesn't really matter.  The question I am trying to answer, for example, is:  If there are 6 charts inserted into chart placeholders (ppPlaceholderChart) on a slide and I select any one of them, from which of the placeholders in the LAYOUT does the selected chart derive its positioning? Put another way:  If I move the selected chart on the slide and then right-click "Reset Slide" to snap the chart back into position, which placeholder in the slide's layout tells the chart how to reposition itself?

Comment: My current approach is to delete one of my charts, for example.  When I do this, a new placeholder whose position and size are derived from the slide's CustomLayout is appended to the slide.  Then, you can use Set oShape = oSlide.Shapes(oSlide.Shapes.Count) and compare the position/size of oShape to shapes in the CustomLayout to find the corresponding placeholder.

Comment: Got it. I'll research this a bit more and let you know what I find out.

Comment: Ryan, I've exhausted research on this and don't believe it's possible in VBA. It is possible in OOXML however. Sorry I couldn't find you a workable bit of code for this.

Comment: No worries.  Thanks for the effort.